# Spring Data Jpa. Sort by list size

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have a restaurant entity and user votes stored in another table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurants")
public class Restaurant extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Vote> votes;

}
```

I removed everything unnecessary to focus on the question. And the Vote class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "votes")
public class Vote extends BaseEntity {  

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Restaurant restaurant;

}
```

Now I want to query the database and get responses with pagination and sorting.

```
public interface RestaurantRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Restaurant, Long> {
     Page<Restaurant> findAllByNameContainsOrAddressContains(String name, String address, Pageable pageable);
}
```

I am using the Pageable object.

```
Pageable pageable = (Pageable) PageRequest.of(0, 10, Sort.by("price"));
```

And everything works very well until I write the field names of the Restaurant class in the Sort.by () method and I know that the table has columns with that name.

But now I want to sort the restaurants by the number of votes given by users. This means that I should not only name the field "votes", but also refer to its method votes.size(). Unfortunately, the syntax of the Sort.by() method does not allow this. I did not find the answer either in Oracle or in the documentation for Spring Date JPA. Please tell me how to implement it.

Comment: Please take a few moments and add the raw query you want to use here.

Comment: Do you mean pure SQL request?

Comment: Yes, please add the native SQL query.

Comment: Use the JPQL instead, or Criteria API and Spring Data JPA includes a `Specifcation` to build the query in type-safe Critera API. Secondly consider QueryDSL(also works with Spring Data JPA) etc.

Comment: SELECT * FROM restaurants rest LEFT JOIN votes vote ON rest.id=vote.restaurant_id GROUP BY rest.id ORDER BY COUNT(vote.id) DESC

Comment: This query is as close as possible to what I need, but it returns the value of two tables. I'm not sure how hibernate will map my object. Of course, I can write manually all the columns I need.